# R: draw unique set of factors for each facet in ggplot2 barchart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

Suppose we have a set of commodities (apples, bananas, potatoes etc) distributed over different continents. We visualize their distribution on continents via faceted barcharts in `ggplot2` package, and these commodities (called in what follows "stuff" field) act as factors to be displayed on x axis. Each continent has its own set of stuff, as shown in the data, although certain commodities can be common (bananas) on two or more continents. Here is the data example in short format. Fields "medium" and "giant" additionally subdivide the market separating out things into medium and big sizes (to be plotted with different colours).

```
    data<-read.csv(text="continent,stuff,average,giant
North America,apples,20,30
North America,bananas,25,32
Europe,bananas,15,25
Europe,potatoes,10,20
Europe,mosquitoes,13,17
Asia,snakes,26,35
Asia,snails,7,15
Asia,pandas,10,20")
```

First we reduce the data to long format, and next plot it via `geom_col()` and faceting technique:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data.tidied<-data %>%
  gather(key=size, value=val,-continent,-stuff)
ggplot(data.tidied,aes(x=stuff,y=val,fill=size))+
geom_col(position="dodge")+
facet_grid(~continent)+coord_flip()
```

[image: barchart with shared factors across facets]

All factors in the stuff are aligned across all continents, although most of them are not needed, so there are many gaps. But we don't need any snails in North America and Europe, it is natural to have this field only for the Asia facet and so on. (To make things clearer, you may think of apples/bananas/potatoes as some geographical localities, unique for a continent: we do not have any California in Europe). So: how to display this situation using nevertheless faceting technique of `ggplot` (or any alternative)? That is: how to draw a unique set of factors for each facet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid` and specify `scales = "free_y"` (has to be `free_y` as you flipped the axes). But it makes the charts look a little odd, in my opinion.

```
data %>% 
  gather(size, val, -continent, -stuff) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(stuff, val)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = size), position = "dodge") + 
    facet_wrap(~continent, scales = "free_y") + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image]